# Building an auction site that uses google checkout

Tags: e-commerce, google-checkout

In an auction site that uses google checkout exclusively how would you transfer money from the buyer's google checkout account to the seller's google checkout account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ask the sellers to provide their own "Buy Now" buttons. The money will be transfered directly from the buyer to the seller's bank account.

If the listing site charges a commission per transaction you can arrange with the sellers to bill them separately.